# UserControl that is also a Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I would like to create a `UserControl` that will have some behavior(animated collapsing...) and some Controls in it (`Rectangle`, `Ellipse`, mostly for design purposes).

However I need it to be a valid `Panel` like `Grid` so I can put more controls in it when designing main window. Controls that will be add to the new `USerControl` in main window design time does not need to interact with components that are added to it when creating a `UserControl`.

How should  I  do this ? Do I have to extends `Control`? I'd prefer to extend just `UserControl`.

Comment: This question of mine is not very clear, I know. I'll try to rewrite it when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking was `ContentPresenter` class in combination with dependency properties. 
More about topic [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6b821cd3-570e-404b-9a45-837c9babff5a) or [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Content_Presenters). Or try [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+contentPresenter+wpf).

Answer (score 1):

`UserControl` is a `ContentControl` which has `Content` property and usually displays it according on `ContentTemplate`. The point I'm leading to is that `UserControl` has 1 item inside of it. Of course you can add `Children` property to your `UserControl` and handle adding/removing of sub-items into some internal `Grid` within your control but it's not what content controls are for.

To host many items you should use a subclass of `Panel`, like `Grid` as you mentioned. All panels have `Children` property with a list of elements arranged on them. You can inherit `Grid` and place some behavior there. E.g. you can make an extension property `MyGrid.Collapsed`, set it on elements within your grid, so it can arrange their positions.

Another option is to subclass `ItemsControl`. Elements placed into it will be displayed according to its `ItemsPanel` template. This approach also gives you an advantage of `ItemsSource` property which can be used to display a list of arbitrary data types by generating elements from them using `ItemTemplate` property.